# C++ - 2D array columnar permutations

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, permutation

I want to find all permutations for solving a transposition cipher using `std::next_permutation`. To do so i created a 2D dynamic char array with the text. I have a key referring to the number of columns for the array.

ex.
with `key = 3`

`1 2 3 
 4 5 6 
 7 8 9`

a possible permutation will be

`2 1 3 
 5 4 6 
 8 7 9`
etc.

Everything works fine until i get `<Unable to read memory> 0xfdfdfdfd <Error reading characters of string.>` always at the same memory `transArr[4][0]` with `key = 6` .

Code:

```
void transpositionCipher(char *text){
    int key = 6, col = 0, row = 0, tempTextLength = length, numOfCol = 0, counter = 0,
    i=0,j=0;
    char **tranArr;
    string fileName;
    ofstream output,transpositions[5];
    output.open("output.txt");

    //for (key = 2; key < 7; key++){
    output << "KEY IS " << key << "\n";
    //fix length to create the columns.
    while (tempTextLength % key != 0){
        if (tempTextLength - 1 % key == 0){
            tempTextLength--;
        }
        else tempTextLength++;
    }

    output << tempTextLength << "\n";
    //fixed column length for each key.
    numOfCol = tempTextLength / key;

    //allocation
    tranArr = new char*[key];
    for (j = 0; j < key; ++j)
        tranArr[j] = new char[numOfCol];
    //fill the array with the text
    for (i = 0; i < tempTextLength; i++){
        if ((text[i] > 96 && text[i] < 123) || i < tempTextLength ){
            if (col == numOfCol){
                row++;
                col = 0;
            }
            if (i >= length){
                tranArr[row][col] = '-';
            }
            else tranArr[row][col] = text[i];
            col++;
        }
    }

    //create the permutations
    fileName = "trans_key_"+to_string(key)+".txt";
    transpositions[key-2].open(fileName);
    transpositions[key-2] << "Permutations with key = " << key << "\n";
    sort(tranArr, tranArr + key);
    do {
        for (int k = 0; k < numOfCol; k++){
            for (int l = 0; l < key; l++){
                transpositions[key-2] << tranArr[l][k] << '\t';
            }
                transpositions[key-2] << "\n";
        }
        transpositions[key-2] << "\n\n";
        counter++;
    } while (next_permutation(tranArr, tranArr + key));

    //deallocation
    for (j = 0; j < key; j++)
        delete[] tranArr[j];
    delete [] tranArr;
    //reset
    row = 0; col = 0; tempTextLength = length; counter = 0, numOfCol = 0;

//}

}
```

I can't understand why this is happening because i iterate inside the array and everything is in place.
The text i am testing on right now is `nalcxehwttdttfseeleedsoaxfeahl`

Comment: In the `fill the array` part of your code, you never checked if `col` goes beyond the bounds of the array.  I bet that it does.  You allocated the array using `key` items, but then you loop assuming that `col < key`.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie so i fixed it .The problem was that during allocation i was allocating `numOfRows`x`key` and when permutating or sorting i was using as parameters the start of the array and the end  start+`key`  but the end of the array was start+`numOfRows` because the first pointer was of `numOfRows` length. I hope my explanation makes sense. I didn't do anything about your suggestion because the fixed lengths keep me inside bounds so nothing much to worry there.

Comment: Well, I took your code and changed it to using `std::vector<std::vector<char>>` (and you should do the same).  Using your input, you do get an out-of-bounds error when reading the data due to `col` going out of bounds.   So there really is an error, it's just that you don't see it because you're using dumb arrays.  To convince yourself, print out the value of `col` when you access `tranArr[row][col]` -- you will see it is `2` when `col` has as valid indices `0` and `1`.

Comment: *I didn't do anything about your suggestion* -- You need to do something --  [Here is your code](http://ideone.com/jHrytY), stripped down to remove the output file stuff and the other things you're doing.  All it does is read exactly as your code does, using the same loop, but instead of arrays, it uses a vector which essentially does the same thing.  See the `out_of_range` exception being thrown?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie  Excuse me for insisting, but if this [example](http://ideone.com/KtTNYI) is right then i am not getting out of bounds. Anyway i am switching to vectors as you proposed but please help me understand why we get different results .

Comment: When you use arrays, they are dumb -- they do **not** check boundary conditions.  If you go beyond the bounds of an array, the behavior of the program is undefined.  So showing "array code" is not convincing.  Second, your example doesn't invoke the magic line of code which I pointed out, and that is `transArray[row][col]` being accessed.  Bottom line -- If I take that code and change it to `std::vector` and actually do something with the vector, it can reveal all of those mistakes.  Off-by-1 errors are the hardest to diagnose, and your original code has one.